# How do I analyze columns in python?

Tags: python

I have a tab delimited table that has multiple columns (1500) and a few rows (10).

Basically how do I make my program look at the columns instead of through the rows? I need to count and organize the columns based on whats in them.

One example is counting how many entries are in the columns that are not '-'.

I think itertools.groupby may be what I'm looking for but I don't know the syntax or if it is even the right thing.

I have been learning programming/python for two weeks so I don't know how to do a lot. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help! I tried each of them and they all did as described and could probably be incorporated into my code (if I was better at python). What I found to work the best for what I was doing to the columns was this:

```
table = []
for each_line in homefile:
##doesn't include first line
        arr1 = each_line.strip("\n").split('\t')
        table.append(arr1)
##created a list of lists(matrix); each row as one entry in table(list)
cols = zip(*table)
##this switches rows and columns
```

Then I was able to do stuff to each column while just treating each as a list containing the entries from each column of the original tab delimited table.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [csvreader doc](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Having csv keyword, you'll find plenty of hits on Google for what you want to do.

[This one for example](http://ask.metafilter.com/142871/Columnoriented-CSV-in-Python)

Comment: Specifically, I with ijoshua's answer in that link because it's so explicit. A 10x1500 table is really quite small in memory. If you get to the point where the data is too large to handle in memory, that's a good indicator that it may be time to start looking at restructuring the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with R (and even if you're not), I recommend the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library. It brings to python the DataFrame structure in R, which allows you to easily manipulate tables by rows or columns (among many other things).

Comment: I have never used R. This probably seems silly, but how do I use libraries?

Comment: If you had the pandas library installed, you would simply say "import pandas" in your python script. Here's the link to download pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/getpandas.html, which includes a link to how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = 'data.txt'
col = 2 # note, this uses a zero-based index.

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        target = line.split()[col]
        print target
```

This finds column `col` in file `filename` and places the string found into variable `target`. You could adjust your actions to target accordingly.

The assumption is that every line will have at as many columns as you'll be looking for and contains data on each line.

Answer (score 0):

If the file's not too big (and it sounds like it's not), then the easiest thing may be to read the whole thing into a table, and then go from there.  E.g.:

```
text = open('some_file.txt').read()
table = [line.split('\t') for line in text.split('\n') if line.strip()]
```

Then you extract a given column as a list using e.g.:

```
col5 = [row[5] for row in table]
```

You can convert the table from a list of rows to a list of columns with:

```
columns = [[row[c] for row in table] for c in range(NUM_COLUMNS)
```

(This assumes you have a fixed number of columns, and that all rows have exactly that number of columns.)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to open a file with the context manager (`with`). Then, you'd like to iterate through the lines of the file (which are the "rows"). You get rid of some whitespace characters and see, if something is left over. Then you split the lines at those positions, where a certain delimiting character occurs, which provides you with the "fields" in this row:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            tokens = line.split(delimiter)
```

This is a powerful concept. Just merge it with your analysis/evaluation code.